How to Solve 'Uncaught Error: Class “WP_Block_Metadata_Registry”' in WordPress site
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "WP_Block_Metadata_Registry" not found in H:\root\home\heritageenergy-002\www\fce\wp-includes\blocks.php:391 
Stack trace: 
#0 H:\root\home\heritageenergy-002\www\fce\wp-includes\blocks\index.php(174): wp_register_block_metadata_collection() 
#1 H:\root\home\heritageenergy-002\www\fce\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(324): wp_register_core_block_metadata_collection() 
#2 H:\root\home\heritageenergy-002\www\fce\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(348): WP_Hook->apply_filters() 
#3 H:\root\home\heritageenergy-002\www\fce\wp-includes\plugin.php(517): WP_Hook->do_action() 
#4 H:\root\home\heritageenergy-002\www\fce\wp-settings.php(700): do_action() 
#5 H:\root\home\heritageenergy-002\www\fce\wp-config.php(106): require_once('H:\\root\\home\\he...') 
#6 H:\root\home\heritageenergy-002\www\fce\wp-load.php(50): require_once('H:\\root\\home\\he...') 
#7 H:\root\home\heritageenergy-002\www\fce\wp-login.php(12): require('H:\\root\\home\\he...') 
#8 {main} thrown in H:\root\home\heritageenergy-002\www\fce\wp-includes\blocks.php on line 391

What I did to try to solve the problem:

Rename both plugins and themes folders and tested
Remove 'wp-includes' and 'wp-admin' folders and replaced with fresh downloads from WordPress.
upgraded PHP Version to 8.1.

But none of the above solution could solve the problem.
Update: I manage to solve the problem by reinstalling a fresh copy of WordPress in the hosting server.

I got this solution from a site
I’d same challenge. Adding the following solved to wp-settings.php line 353 solved it.

require ABSPATH . WPINC . ‘/class-wp-block-metadata-registry.php’;


I had the same error, in my case between a Friday and it was working perfectly, in the afternoon I touched a couple of plugins and the following Tuesday it no longer worked. I have tried to delete the plugins that I touched from the terminal. It hasn't worked for me but maybe it will for you. In the end I reinstalled wordpress and started from scratch
Feedback

Hi, please read how to answer. If this doesn't work for you, why post an answer?

Why are you reposting the same thing over and over? There is a reason your answer gets deleted. Please see [answer]
